# How to show command parameters in notify-osd message?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I want to use `notify-osd` to show desktop notifications. A value given as input parameter should also be displayed.

Script:

```sh
param="parameter $1"
echo "${param}"
echo 'notify-send "param no value"' | at now
echo 'notify-send "${param}" "param with value"' | at now
```

Problem: The first notification displays correctly. But the notification using `${param}` is never shown. Why?

(`at now` will later on of course be replaced by scheduled time)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the second `${param}` is inside single quotes, which means it gets interpreted when the command is run by at, which did not inherit the variable, as it was not exported.

Since it is an empty string at that point, `notify-send` exits with an error, as a non-empty summary is required.

You can `export` a variable to contain the value you wish to use, and use that variable inside the single quotes, to get the value passed in. Or, as `at` reads from *stdin*, you can just dump a script directly without extraneous escaping, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
at now << EOF
notify-send "${param}" "param with value"
EOF
```

Comment: could you give an example how to fix this?